# select sibling button based on child description

Tags: android, listview, android-uiautomator

I have an app with different `ListView`s for different items. I am trying to click on `Button` by specifying for example View2 using uiautomator. I have not had any luck with any code so far. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I got this so far but it seems to always click on View1's Button, not view 2.

```
    UiScrollable list = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
    UiObject view = list.getChildByDescription(new UiSelector().className("android.view.View"), "View2", true);

    UiObject button = view.getFromParent(new UiSelector().description("Button"));
    button.click();
```

Here is what the xml looks like.

```
View    
    ListView
       View
          View (Description "View1")
    Button (Description "button")
    ListView
       View
          View (Description "View2")
    Button (Description "button")
    ListView
       View
          View (Description "View3")
    Button (Description "button")
    ListView
       View
          View (Description "View4")
    Button (Description "button")
```

Comment: can you upload your uiautomator dump and screenshot taken from uiautomatorviewer and share link ? I will give it a try. For time being you can click the button by specifying `.instance(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Look on the hierarchy of views .,. if ur using a adapter u can get the everything from adapter.getitem(position) or have an ViewGroup cast on each items.